# How to get an href from an external website?

Tags: jquery, html, get, href

I'm trying to get an `href` element from an external site for which I am not the administrator.

The code of this `href` is like:

```
<a href="?form=397&amp&id=45950&amp&act=act">Action</a>
```

I want only to get a: `'?form=397&amp&id=45950&amp&act=act'.`

How can I do that? Maybe using JQuery?

Comment: You can't! If the site supports CORS or JSONP you can send a request and get a response, but you can't scrape the HTML, you'll need to do that serverside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to run into issues because of cross-domain browser restrictions. There is an ajax plugin that you could use if you want to use JS:

https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

then just use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.somewebsite.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Now that is a really nice utility! It should be mentioned that it works because it uses YQL as the backend to retrieve the crossdomain url. But still great! :D

Comment: I liked it, and I will use it in my project! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you edited your answer to say:

> How can I do that? Eg. using JQuery. **It`s just eg**.

Since using jquery was only eg, here is a non-jquery solution:

```
$ curl 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hDPyZ2Ne' |sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
```

(replace that url for the url of your site)

That line would be executed on a *nix terminal. That will output

```
?form=397&amp&id=45950&amp&act=act
```

Now, is *completly* **impossible** to do it with jquery? The way you mean it, yeah, but if you use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), you could execute your own js over the page DOM.

And here is a phantomjs script which uses jquery to do it:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
var url = 'http://...put your url here';      
page.open(url, function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        var href = page.evaluate(function() {
            return $('a').attr('href');
        });
        console.log(href);
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: The method *Front End Guy* gave you is pretty good too.